# delete shapekey keyframes with python

Tags: keyframes, shape-keys

I thought this would be straight forward, but I'm still struggling to learn the API. I need to delete keyframes for shape keys on the selected or active objects (either or really at this point) For whatever reason this doesn't seem to work for shape keys.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for ob in context.selected_objects:

    ob.animation_data_clear()
```

Anyone any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Object animations are at object level (like location).

Shape keys animations are as its own data level. Add the line below:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    ob.animation_data_clear()
    ob.data.shape_keys.animation_data_clear() # <<<<
```

Comment: thank you! something to get used to, but makes sense.